# ASPNETCORE 5.0 with jsGrid (loadData problem)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, jsgrid

I got some problem with jsgrid while loading some data (failed to load data)

here is my code

Client:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "50%",
            width: "100%",

            filtering: true,
            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,

            pageSize: 10,
            pageButtonCount: 5,

            deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete client?",

            controller: {
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    var d = $.Deferred();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Category", "Management")' + '?method=' + 'GET',
                        data: filter,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        d.resolve(response.value);
                    });
                    return d.promise();
                }
                
            },

            fields: [
                { name: "Categoria", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "Id", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { name: "Nome", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "Valor", type: "number", width: 200 },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Category(string method, [FromBody] Product filter)
{
    if(method.ToUpper() == "GET")
    {
        var aa = productRepository.GetProducts.ToList();
        return StatusCode(200, aa);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my debugging result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK1kt.jpg)

successfully loaded data! but, blow this code,

d.resolve(response.value);

non-value exist in response.value.. how can I add or create it?

http://js-grid.com/docs/

jsgrid homepage said

loadData is a function returning an array of data or jQuery promise that will be resolved with an array of data (when pageLoading is true instead of object the structure { data: [items], itemsCount: [total items count] } should be returned). Accepts filter parameter including current filter options and paging parameters when pageLoading is true.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

I think I got some problem in backend code

please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Category(string method, [FromBody] Product filter)
{
    if(method.ToUpper() == "GET")
    {
        var aa = productRepository.GetProducts.ToList();
        return Json(aa);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

in the method. Probably you don't return a Json object.

Comment: still, it doesn't not work...
i just give up to use jsgrid...